# Find a string between 2 static element groups

Tags: adobe-indesign, grep, regex

I want to find all textblocks in InDesign with Grep that are between "Article: " and "— " I already tried to understand what they do here: https://indesignsecrets.com/findbetween-a-useful-grep-string.php but honestly I don't understand it. Basically

So e.g. this is what I have multiple times (of course with different numbers)
and I want to find the bold highlighted block

```
(?<=Article:\t).*?(?= —)
```

I suppose it must be something like

```
(?<=Article:    ).*?(?=  —)
```

but that doesn't deliver me anything

Comment: But do you really have that many spaces or did you intend to use `\t`?

Comment: @joojaa I intended to use \t but Stackexchange transformed that. Originally the code is (which doesn't work is
(?<=Article:\t).*?(?=  —)

Comment: Is it better now?

Comment: @joojaa How you mean? Still I get nothing output (as I didn't change anything :))

Comment: I fixed the question text for you still no idea what the other regex is supposed to be

Comment: Have you tried using the special InDesign escape sequence for the em dash (i.e., in the GREP panel, click on the @-right-arrow button and choose em dashes from the ‘dashes and hyphens’ subcategory)? According to the page you link to, the code for it is `~_`. And what do you mean by “of course with different numbers”? What numbers?